# How to pass the ID of a component to its prop function?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Snakbar component (with a close button) defined using the material UI component Snak to display messages, which is defined as shown below:

```
function Snackbar({ ...props }) {
  const { classes, message, color, close, icon, id } = props;
  var action = [];
  if (close !== undefined) {
    action = [
      <IconButton
        className={classes.iconButton}
        key="close"
        aria-label="Close"
        onClick={() => props.closeMessage(id)}
      >
        <Close className={classes.close} />
      </IconButton>
    ];
  }
  return (
    <Snack
      message={
        <div>
          <span>{message}</span>
        </div>
      }
      action={action}
    />
  );
}
```

I want to create a list of messages using the Snakbar component each with their own id. When I click the the close button in any of the messages, the deleteMessage function should be called to delete that particular message from the database. When I test the button click using a console.log, the ID of the corresponding message is shown as undefined.

Rendering the Message List:

```
    for (let [key, message] of Object.entries(this.props.messages)){
          data.push(
             <Snackbar
                id = {key}
                message={message.title}
                close
                closeMessage={(key) => this.deleteMessage(key)}
              />
          )
      }

   return(
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={8}>
           <div>{data}</div>
        </GridItem>
  )
```

Function:

```
deleteMessage = (key) => {
    console.log("delete button clicked", key)
  }
```

What is the correct way to pass the component ID to the function?

Comment: Looks fine, at least at a glance... Could You add a piece of code, that You use to render the `<Snackbar />` components?

Comment: I added the code segment that renders the messages list

Comment: Could you show us `message` structure, I believe your `Object.entries` does not return a correct key, that's why your id is `undefined`. I'd like to see whole `MessageList` code